# Скопировать файл по сети php

Tags: php

Как получить доступ к файлу в классе ? Есть база данных в локальной сети и если я пытаюсь вызвать метод copyFile который копирует базу , то ничего не происходит
Но если я создам обычный файл php и попробую скопировать то он успешно копируется, только внутри класса не хоче, подскажите что я не так делаю ?

```
class Ibase
{

    protected $result = [];
    protected $db;
    protected $dbName;

    public $newfile = '/var/www/html/Database.mdb';
    public $file = 'smb://test:666@136.108.3.150/Test/Database.mdb';

    
    function __construct($dbName){

        $this->dbName = $dbName;
        $this->connectBase();
    }

    public function copyFile(){
        copy($this->$file, $this->$newfile);
    }

    private function connectBase(){

        $this->db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER=MDBTools; DBQ=$this->dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
    }

    public function getSale(){

        $this->result = $this->db->query('SELECT Sale FROM CurrentState')->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function printArray(){
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->result);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    function __destruct(){

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638744/how-to-php-copy-across-smb-mount смотрите в сторону прав доступа. И ничего не происходить не может. Вы просто не читаете ошибки, а подавляете их

Comment: Почему вне класа все прекрасно работает ?